# Dictionary to get class type to instantiate

Tags: python-3.x, loops, class

I want to iterate over a dictionary in python. The values are types.

```
class_dict = {'ClassA': ClassA, 'ClassB': ClassB}
```

In the iteration I would like to do something like this:

```
for key, value in class_dict.items():
    instance = value(params)
    instance.do_method(params)
```

Essentially each iteration would create an instance of the class defined in the value and run it's class methods etc.

I am curious as to why this actually works, and what happens to value when it is used. Does it get instantiated in the dictionary or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python classes are objects themselves - they are instances of `type` (or another metaclass). So you can have a reference to a class in a variable or a data structure, such as your dictionary. Classes are also callable; normally, "calling" them creates a new instance of the class.

When the dictionary holds a reference to a class, that doesn't create an instance of the class, since you didn't "call" the class to create an instance. The instances are created in your loop, where `key` is the class name (a string) and `value` is the class itself; the expression `value(params)` creates the instance, because it "calls" the class. The instance is not stored in the dictionary because you didn't write any code to put it there.